# anchor tag not working in Desktop or Salesforce1

Tags: google-maps, salesforce, visualforce

I am displaying marker for every near by account and below anchor tag should navigate to the respective account upon clicking it.I have used the code in Workbook,but it works neither in Desktop nor in Salesforce1.I have checked posts where users reported that redirection is happening to wrong page.But in my case page just refreshes and stays on the same page.Please help

```
try{
            if(sforce.one){
                 accountNavUrl = 'javascript:sforce.one.navigateToSObject(\'' + account.Id + '\')';
             }
} catch(err) {
             console.log(err);
             var dId=account.Id;
             accountNavUrl= '\\' + account.Id;
}
console.log('-->'+accountNavUrl );
var content='<a href src="'+accountNavUrl +'" >'+account.Name+ '</a><br/>'+account.BillingStreet +'<br/>' + account.BillingCity +'<br/>' + account.BillingCountry;
```

Below is my whole code

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountMapExt" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
    <apex:includeScript value="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" />  

  <style>
        html, body { height: 100%; }    
        .page-map, .ui-content, #map-canvas { width: 100%; height:100%; padding: 0; }
        #map-canvas { height: min-height: 100%; }
  </style>
  <script>
      var lat;
      var lon;
        function initialize(){ 
            if(navigator.geolocation){
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    function(position){
                        lat=position.coords.latitude;
                        lon=position.coords.longitude;
                        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.AccountMapExt.getNearby}',lat, lon,
                              function(result, event){
                                    if (event.status) {
                                           console.log('->'+lat+' '+lon+' '+result);
                                           createMap(lat, lon, result);
                                    } else if (event.type ==='exception') {
                                            //exception case code
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                    },
                                    {escape: true}
                        );                        
                    }
                );
            } 

        }    
        function createMap(lat,lon,accounts){
                console.log('Calling map '+ lat+' '+lon);
                var currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);            
                var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
                    center: currentPosition, 
                    zoom: 13,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
                var positionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: currentPosition,
                    icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png'
                });

                for(var i=0; i<accounts.length;i++){
                    account= accounts[i];
                    console.log(accounts[i]);
                    setupMarker();
                }                

                function setupMarker(){
                    var accountNavUrl;
                    try{
                        if(sforce.one){
                            accountNavUrl = 'javascript:sforce.one.navigateToSObject(\'' + account.Id + '\')';

                        }
                    } catch(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        var dId=account.Id;
                        accountNavUrl= '\\' + account.Id;
                    }
                    console.log('-->'+accountNavUrl );
                    var content='<a href src="'+accountNavUrl +'" >'+account.Name+ '</a><br/>'+account.BillingStreet +'<br/>' + account.BillingCity +'<br/>' + account.BillingCountry;
                    //Create the callout that will pop up on the marker
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content});
                    //Place the marker
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(account.BillingLatitude,account.BillingLongitude)}
                    );              

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });                          
                }  
                var mapBoundary = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                mapBoundary.extend(currentPosition);                    
         }       
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);           
  </script>

    <body style="font-family: Arial; border: 0 none;">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>    
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code did the trick!

```
            var accountNavUrl;
            try{
                if(sforce.one){
                    accountNavUrl='<a href="javascript:sforce.one.navigateToSObject(\''+account.Id+'\');">';
                }
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
                accountNavUrl='<a href="../' + account.Id + '" target="_parent">';                        
            }
            console.log('-->'+accountNavUrl );
            var content=accountNavUrl+account.Name+ '</a><br/>'+account.BillingStreet +'<br/>' + account.BillingCity +'<br/>' + account.BillingCountry;
```